# Spring and Hibernate upgradation from 4.x to 5.x

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jboss

As part of security upgrade I am trying to upgrade both Spring and hibernate jars to 5.x version due to which I faced many errors. The main issue right now is that my UI screen is blank for all fields.For example there are screens like currency codes,user profile,fee report.Only the field is visible in screen but not the entire page related to it.Could someone please help on this.

Initially there was a main screen which was blank and had error as "Data store implementation not found for Dialect : null"
This got resolved after I edited `hibernate.properties` file where previously it was,

```
hibernate.transaction.factory_class =org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory
hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class=org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup
```

And I changed it to,

```
Hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class=jta

Hibernate.transaction.jta.platform=<>
```

After doing the above change, All the fields in the screen got visible(Basically that screen is the landing page after login which has quick links to other screens)

Now am stuck on what to do to make the rest of screens visible

I am completely new to hibernate and spring and need to work on this as security upgrade so I don't know exactly what is going wrong here..so any help is much appreciated.

My `hibernate.properties` file

```
#hibernate.dialect =org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
#hibernate.dialect =org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.dialect_resolvers=com.abcgroup.ss.soa.commons.service.config.ssDialectResolver
hibernate.show_sql =false
hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers =false
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto =validate
hibernate.connection.autocommit =false
hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class=jta
hibernate.transaction.jta.platform=<>
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
hibernate.development.mode=true
process.container.mode=false
hibernate.connection.release_mode=on_close
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2">
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
  xmlns:orm="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd">

  <persistence-unit name="org.jbpm.persistence.jpa" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/Data</jta-data-source>
      <mapping-file>META-INF/JBPMorm.xml</mapping-file>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/Taskorm.xml</mapping-file>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/TaskAuditorm.xml</mapping-file>
     <class>org.jbpm.persistence.processinstance.ProcessInstanceInfo</class>
    <class>org.drools.persistence.info.SessionInfo</class>
    <class>org.drools.persistence.info.WorkItemInfo</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.process.audit.ProcessInstanceLog</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.process.audit.NodeInstanceLog</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.process.audit.VariableInstanceLog</class>
    
    <class>org.jbpm.persistence.correlation.CorrelationKeyInfo</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.persistence.correlation.CorrelationPropertyInfo</class>
    
    <!-- manager -->
    <class>org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.jpa.ContextMappingInfo</class>
    
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.AttachmentImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.ContentImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.BooleanExpressionImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.CommentImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.DeadlineImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.DelegationImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.EscalationImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.GroupImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.I18NTextImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.NotificationImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.EmailNotificationImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.EmailNotificationHeaderImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.PeopleAssignmentsImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.ReassignmentImpl</class>
    
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.TaskImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.TaskDataImpl</class>
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.impl.model.UserImpl</class>
    
    <!--BAM for task service -->
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.audit.impl.model.BAMTaskSummaryImpl</class>
    
    <!-- Event Classes -->
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.audit.impl.model.TaskEventImpl</class>
    
    <!-- Task Audit Classes --> 
    <class>org.jbpm.services.task.audit.impl.model.AuditTaskImpl</class>

    <properties>
       <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" /> 
    
<!--    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="com.abcgroup.wfm.web.UserDialect" />  -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect_resolvers" value="com.abcgroup.wfm.web.WorkflowDialectResolver"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />
    <!-- <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="hibernate3-bundled" /> -->
    <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate.hibernate42"/>
    <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3" />
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
    <!-- <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="com.abcgroup.wfm.util.JBPMTransactionManagerLookup" />  -->
    <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false" />
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />  
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class" value="jta" />

  </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My **Jboss** log which might be useful to identify the issue

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : <>

2023-01-21 13:53:47,061 WARN [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext] (default task-3) Could not introspect Hibernate JtaPlatform for SpringJtaSessionContext: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform]

2023-01-21 13:53:25,601 INFO [org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker] (default task-3) Bean 'xAppConfig' of type [com.abcgroup.x.soa.commons.service.config.xAppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1a31b458] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

2023-01-21 13:53:24,364 INFO [stdout] (default task-3) Query is SELECT sp_dda_en from staff_profile WHERE SP_STAFF_ID = ?

2023-01-21 13:49:55,314 INFO [org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 298) Bean 'xAppConfig' of type [com.abcgroup.x.soa.commons.service.config.XAppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1a31b458] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

2023-01-21 13:49:55,315 WARN [org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 298) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xService' defined in com.abcgroup.x.soa.commons.service.config.XAppConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.abcgroup.x.soa.commons.service.datastore.DataStoreService]: Factory method 'getXService' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

2023-01-21 13:49:55,320 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 298) java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Please use some formatting as your post (especially the properties, exception) are totally unreadable without them. There are code formatting tags which you should use so it remains readable.

Comment: Hope it's readable now?

Comment: Have you actually read the error? `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : <>` is pretty clear. In your `hibernate.properties` that is the value for your jta platform variable, which isn't a proper name. Either remove that line or use the same value as you have in your `persistence.xml`. Or even better move all the properties from the `hibernate.properties` to the `persistence.xml` so that you hvae all the configuration in one place.

Comment: Hi,thanks for replying and yes I can see that the error is due to <> but if I remove that jta.platform = <> the main screen which I resolved gets blank again with error prompt as Data store implementation not found for Dialect : null ...which is why I kept it as it is and I also tried with jta.platform = the value given in persistence.xml file which eventually leads to Application Error in the Login page....Or do I have to give it as hibernate.transaction.jta.platform=<org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform>

Comment: It needs to be a proper classname something starting with `<` and ending with `>` is a proper classname. I would first start by simplifying your configuration by moving everything to the `persistence.xml` that way you at least know where the values are coming from, after that fix the error by modifying the `persistence.xml`.

Comment: Ok, so it's not a problem if there is nothing in my hibernate.properties file?

Comment: The file isn't even required, assuming that you are using JPA (`LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory`) and not plain Hibernate (`LocalSessionFactoryBean`) for the configuration.

Comment: Hi, so after editing hibernate.transaction.jta.platform=org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform ....the jboss error log has become from unable to resolve class <> to Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [<org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform>] as strategy [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform] .... Can u help on this

Comment: You really should read the error. It basically says that the class you are using doesn't exists.

Comment: isn't that a class present in hibernate 5.4.x? Or is it part of hibernate 4.x? I am sorry but I really have no idea related to this

Comment: When upgrading don't blindly upgrade but read the update notices generally they contain information on which classes got removed, renamed etc. I don't know which 5 version you are using (that isn't in the question) but it appears that the class doesn't exists anymore, you need to figure out yourself which one you need.

Comment: I am upgrading from 4.2.0.Final to 5.4.32.Final and I have searched my best to identify the cause but nothing comes up